# Сводная информация в админке Django

Tags: django-admin

Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть для того что бы в админке django вывести данные вот в таком формате как на картинке?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Могу посоветовать использовать [библиотеку Django-Import-Export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) для экспорта данных в excel формате. Чтобы **установить** библиотеку: pip install django-import-export
И прописать следующее в **settings.py**: INSTALLED_APPS = ( ... #другие приложения 'import_export', ) Затем установим библиотеке, откуда экспортировать/импортировать данные: # app/admin.py from import_export import resources from core.models import Book class BookResource(resources.ModelResource): class Meta: model = Book Теперь, мы можем экспортировать данные в удобном вам